# Invalid response when I use my socket code

Tags: python, sockets, http

I have a socket test file, and running:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()

sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
sock.listen(5)


while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    data = conn.recv(8096)
    print(data)
    conn.send(b'123456')
    conn.close()
```

when I use browser request the `127.0.0.1:8080`, but in my browser there only get invalid response error:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no response header, you should add the response header:

```
conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')  
conn.send(b'123456')
```